# How to remove item from enumerated list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, zip, enumerate

Let's say I have two lists of names and birth years, then I decide to zip them enumerate them, like so:

```
names = ['Boris', 'Billy', 'Tod']
dates = ['1990', '1992', '1994']

pairs = list(zip(names,dates))
pairs_num = list(enumerate(pairs,start=1))
```

What if, at this point, I need to remove one of the items in `pairs_num` knowing just the name, e.g. 'Boris'. How do I go about that?

Comment: Do you want to keep the original indexes from `enumerate()`, or get new indexes from the list with removed elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `filter`.

**Ex:**

```
names = ['Boris', 'Billy', 'Tod']
dates = ['1990', '1992', '1994']

pairs = list(zip(names,dates))
pairs_num = list(enumerate(pairs,start=1))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x[1][0] != 'Boris', pairs_num)))
```

**Output:**

```
[(2, ('Billy', '1992')), (3, ('Tod', '1994'))]
```

But it would be better if you had a `dict` instead of a `list`. That way you can delete the item by using name as key.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary to store the pairs that way it is easier to delete any pair in the dictionary.

**code**

```
names = ['Boris', 'Billy', 'Tod']
dates = ['1990', '1992', '1994']

pairs = dict((name, date) for name, date in zip(names, dates))
del pairs["Boris"]
print(pairs)
```

**output**

```
{'Billy': '1992', 'Tod': '1994'}
```

Comment: Shorter would be `pairs = dict(zip(names, dates))`

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Sure! Thanks :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `list(enumerate(pairs,start=1))` and check if at the second item in the first index if it equal to `Boris` and if so not to include the item.

```
names = ['Boris', 'Billy', 'Tod']
dates = ['1990', '1992', '1994']

pairs = list(zip(names,dates))
pairs_num = [i for i in list(enumerate(pairs,start=1)) if i[1][0] != 'Boris']
print(pairs_num)
```

Output

```
[(2, ('Billy', '1992')), (3, ('Tod', '1994'))]
```